# PostgresSQL - Return first occurence in table's select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, **documents** and **document_type**.

**documents**

| id | title | id_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | document 1 | 1 |
| 2 | document 2 | 1 |
| 3 | document 3 | 2 |

**document_type**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type 1 |
| 2 | type 2 |

I want to select only the first document considering the id_type. Example, the select query should return:

| id | title | id_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | document 1 | 1 |
| 3 | document 3 | 2 |

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (d.id_type) d.*
from documents d
order by d.id_type, d.id
```